# how to store JDialog in JDialog object created by JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, storing-data

I create JDialog JOptionPane like

```
JOptionPane. showMessageDialog(null, "Last Warning!","Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

this shows a Dialog imdietly and return void so I cant store it in JDialog varible.

I want to do something like this

```
JDialog warning = JOptionPane. showMessageDialog(null, "Last Warning!","Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
// some code
warning.setVisible(true);
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOptionPane` has both static utility methods for convenience, and allows instance creation for custom operation, like you want. The way to do it is more verbose, but is more flexible:

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Last Warning!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
JDialog warning = pane.createDialog("Warning");

// more code...

warning.setVisible(true);
```

For more info, I suggest looking at the source code for `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)`, as it shows how to configure the dialog for various messages types, initial value, etc. Alernatively, have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) from the Java Tutorials.